# How do I find the other components?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

I always have trouble when working in spherical coordinates.

Given $|V|$ and the cartesian components $V_x,V_y,V_z$ I want to find the spherical components $V_r,V_\theta,V_\phi$. As far as I understand $V_r=|V|$, but how do I find the other components?

Comment: What is $|V|$? Is it a generic subset of $\mathbb R^3$ ?

Comment: @Vajra $|V|=\sqrt{V_x^2+V_y^2+V_z^2}$

Comment: So $|V|$ is a real number but it's not clear to me what $V_x,V_y,V_z$  are.

Comment: @Vajra They are the components of the vector in cartesian coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivially, $\theta=\cos^{-1}{V_z \over \sqrt{V_x^2+V_y^2}}$ and $\phi=\tan^{-1}{V_y \over V_x} (+\pi)$ but these are not `components of a vector' as you can't add two vectors by adding these 'components', or multiply them by a scalar.

Comment: Please do not answer very low quality questions.  Please review [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|142.0215).